# Ruby iterate version number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, makefile

I'm building a pipeline to deploy a gem to Rubygems. The general consensus is that it will read a change in the github library and iterate the minor in the version. I'm struggling to come up with an idea of how to do this, as it stands, a makefile will be used to execute something that iterates the `version.rb` file:

eg: `make deploy update=minor`

or something of sort, but i'm not sure on how to go about iterating the file in a 'ruby'y way rather than trying to amend it as if it's just another text file.

The current version file looks like:

```
module Pugin
  release_no = 0
  patch_no = 1
  hotfix_no = 0
  VERSION = release_no.to_s + "." + patch_no.to_s + "." + hotfix_no.to_s
end
```

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to use string interpolation or `Array#join` for the last line, i.e. `"#{release_no}.#{patch_no}.#{hotfix_no}"` or `[release_no, patch_no, hotfix_no].join('.')`. And I'd use `MAJOR`, `MINOR`, `PATCH` instead of local variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no reason to reinvent a wheel, there is [`Gem::Version`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Version.html):

```
require 'rubygems/version.rb'
#⇒ false
gv = Gem::Version.new "1.0.2.a"
#⇒ #<Gem::Version "1.0.2.a">
gv.segments
#⇒ [1, 0, 2, "a"]
gv.release
#⇒ #<Gem::Version "1.0.2">
gv.bump
#⇒ #<Gem::Version "1.1">
```

I believe you got the idea.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is probably to move the pure version to a text file and then read it in the version.rb

version.txt:

```
"1.2.3"
```

pugin.rb:

```
module Pugin
  VERSION = File.read("version.txt").split("\n").first
end
```

To increment the version have a ruby script that parses the version:

```
major, minor, patch = File.read("version.txt").
                           split("\n").
                           first.
                           split(".").
                           map(&:to_i)
```

Then you can easily increment the part you want and write it back to the file

```
minor += 1
File.open("version.txt", "wb") {|f| f.write("#{major}.#{minor}.#{patch}")}
```